# Empty codeception report, causes Jenkins build failure

Tags: yii, jenkins, codeception

In our Yii project we're using Jenkins CI and Codeception for different types of tests. The problem is, that codeception report is empty, which causes whole Jenkins build failure.

All tests are running without errors. Jenkins execute shell for codeception:

```
php codecept.phar run --xml --html
```

Console output error line which causes failure:

```
[xUnit] [ERROR] - The result file '/var/lib/jenkins/jobs/project/workspace/code/protected/tests/_output/report.xml' for the metric 'PHPUnit' is empty. The result file has been skipped.
```

I understand simple logic, if report is empty -> build failed. But why is report empty? Is that a bug or can I do something about this?

Comment: there is an option "Skip if there are no test files". Maybe after generating raport check if it's empty and, if so, delete it?

Comment: Didn't understand what do you mean. There are tests, there should be generated report and I need this report for another plugin, which makes metrics. What should I try to delete?

Comment: sorry, i thought since there are no errors report should be empty

Comment: Okey, no problem :)
Even if all tests are done without errors - report contains some information about amount of tests, assertions, times for executing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was, that in one of our tearDowns was the following line:

```
Yii::app()->end();
```

which makes Yii-Application die. For some reasons this caused that codeception has not generated the report.